# Program crash in boost::signal<event> dtor

Tags: c++, boost-signals

I have a very complex software where I got random crash (mainly in release mode and I cannot easily build a SSCCE), and  tracked the crash in the destructor of `boost::signal1<event>` .

That signal object is used (subscribe/unsubscribe) by several object and used in a multi-threaded software (i mean send by multiple thread and receive by multiple thread).

I heard that `boost::signal2` is thread-safe and I would like to know if regarding the symptom description, you have the same feeling than me ? That I need to use the **Signal2**

Comments, Feelings, and feedback are welcome, as i start to rebuild boost for signal2!

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't already protecting your multi-threaded subscribe/disconnect/RAII disconnect with a mutex then you absolutely need to be using `signals2` instead of `signals`.